# Url not found, click on Password reset link in gmail

Tags: laravel

I got an error in reset password link "Object not found at this url when click on the reset link in gmail-http://localhost/password/reset/8fa85663874bce909623d285a255b976730d9ac509867c55fd820f78b176bfd5 "

ResetPasswordController.php

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (auth()->user()->is_admin == 1) {
        return 'admin/home';
    } elseif (auth()->user()->is_admin == 2) {
        return 'designpages/index';
    } else {
        return 'designpages/index';
    }
}

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

view.php

```
<form method="POST" action="/password/reset" class="account_form">
    @csrf

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
    <div class="field-form">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="field-text{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email"
               value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="E-Mail Address" required autofocus>

        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="field-form">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="field-text{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
               name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="field-form">
        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="field-text" name="password_confirmation"
               placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field-form field-submit">
        <button type="submit" class="awe-btn awe-btn-13">
            {{ __('Reset Password') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: return redirect('designpages/index'); not 'designpages/index' this is a string

Comment: did you check your log ? What is inside "index" action on "designpages" controller ( assumes the controller will be this )

Comment: 'designpages/index this is only use for redirect purpose.After reset password.

Comment: please show your web.php

Comment: @akash actually i am not writing anything on web.php file

Comment: What is the url you're using to access your site? Also, what are you using as a local server?

Comment: Auth:: routes (); this is by default on web.php file when run the command php artisan make:auth after that I register and login  that correctly work and in reset password option when I send the mail and click on the reset link through the gmail then I got the error.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i got it your issue. as you can see in your url there is your folder name and public is missing. so it generates error."http://localhost/password/reset/8fa85663874bce909623d285a255b976730d9ac509867c55fd820f78b176bfd5"

```php
'/someurl'    // its makes a proper url when we mount our project folder as document root in apache2 server. otherwise its gives your wrong url -- "http://localhost/password/reset"
```

```php
url('/someurl');  // by using this gives you correct url -- "http://localhost/yourfolder/public/reset/password"
```

## solution = if we are not using url() helper. then edit your APP_URL in your .env file.

```php
APP_URL=http://localhost/yourfolder/public
```

then hit

```php
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it should fix the issue.

Comment: @akash i using this but not worked. {{ route('password.update') }}

Comment: yaa, actually i am using the default forget  password using the command php artisan make:auth .sending mail is properly worked but the reset link url is not found from gmail

Comment: @akash i got the url - http://localhost/password/reset/8fa85663874bce909623d285a255b976730d9ac509867c55fd820f78b176bfd5 instead of -http://localhost/projectname/password/reset/8fa85663874bce909623d285a255b976730d9ac509867c55fd820f78b176bfd5

Comment: @Renu In my case my solution working properly. i just tested.

Comment: in my gmail i am getting this http://localhost/tt/public/password/reset/45ab90bd17cebf767b9ba214be6bae0a5242b62148c012192dfd399ca9fba170

Comment: @akash - ok i will check